# Android Wear - code to read LogCat output programmatically and continuously is not working

Tags: android, logcat

Hi everyone I recently wrote some code to read LogCat output continuously within a background Thread started by a background Service in my app. I do not think there are errors in my code but it's not working.

In my **Thread**, I have:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Process process = null;
    String cmd = "logcat -v time | grep 'AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus()'";

    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("logcat -c" + "\n");
        os.writeBytes(cmd + "\n");
        os.flush();
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    String line;

    try {
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
            Log.e(StaticVal.TAG, line);

            // code for write line to my own log file
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

I also added permission to manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />`

However, when I plug my device with PC and test it with Android Studio,  `Log.e(StaticVal.TAG, line);` did not print out the results and nothing wrote into my own log file.

Any help is appreciated!

(Directly run `logcat -v time | grep 'AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus()'` on my device through adb terminal get the results as expected)

Comment: Btw I have read related questions in stackoverflow and none of them helped...

Answer (score 0):

At this time, permission READ_LOGS is not granted on WearOS. Even on standard OS, you now have to run a pm grant command, but it's not working on WearOS.

A pity as I wanted to get app's log from end-user under specific circumstances, but it's just plain impossible.